# Fast report chart from "n" detail fild´s

Tags: delphi, charts, fastreport

i have a fast report where i whant to add a chart where data come from adoquery and i filter data for the first master record averything work´s nice for the next it doesente work how can i work this problem ?

Master table (numeracao_1)Autoenc
Detail table (numeracao_1) [image]

```
SELECT   Count(  GrauAnomalia and Anomaliatipo) AS SomaDeGrauAnomalia,GrauAnomalia , Anomaliatipo   from   Vibrometria_Sub_Sub
 where numeracao_1=:numeracao_1                                                                  GROUP BY GrauAnomalia ,Anomaliatipo
```

Comment: Such problems should be reported on FastReport's forums, not on a programming website, if you're using their designer.  If you're using code, then post your Pascal CODE, not the picture.  As it stands if this is really a report designer problem, this isn't a programming question, and doesn't belong on stack overflow.    As for "help me debug my SQL Statements against my DB", that's getting pretty close to not-a-programming problem since we don't have your databases to try it against.

Comment: I ask is there a nother way for counting the values for the clied dateset since eache time the master datset chages reset´s the value SELECT Count( GrauAnomalia and Anomaliatipo) AS SomaDeGrauAnomalia,GrauAnomalia , Anomaliatipo from Vibrometria_Sub_Sub where numeracao_1=:numeracao_1

Comment: That still seems like a question for the Fast Report forums, because you're using their designer, not writing code. This is a programming answers site, not a using-someones-reporting-system site.